# What % of traffic are logged in?

Tags: discussion

Does anyone have any idea what percentage of traffic to Salesforce StackExchange are logged in vs anonymous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to tell *for certain* from the data that we're given, but if I had to make an educated guess, I'd say it's close to 99.83% anonymous. This is based on the fact that we're averaging about 54 questions a day, but getting hit with 31,000+ search hits per day. Even for those regular users like myself that use Google to find our old questions, there's only about 36,000 registered users, which means that to have any statistical "logged in" meaning, we'd have to have the top 86% of our users doing a search a day, which is unlikely, since our core user base is much, much smaller than that. So, I'm going to go with a final guesstimate of 99% +/- 1% of our traffic is anonymous. Crazy, huh?

Comment: Bonkers. How involved are people who work at Salesforce?

Comment: @Robs They tend to jump in from time to time. I don't know how many of our users are salesforce.com employees, but there's probably at least 10-20. They tend to answer the difficult questions in their area of expertise (e.g. the Lightning team answers questions about Lightning). They may not post consistently, but they do post with all the expertise you'd expect from someone that literally *wrote* the thing they're posting about. And I don't think they've ever failed to answer a question after being brought to attention on Twitter.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  It would be great if they adopted Salesforce StackExchange as their primary forum location. Because the official forums are awful to use.

Comment: @Robs That's why I left developer.salesforce.com five years ago. And I'm still the #2 highest score on the system. I loved helping people, but the format here is more conducive to helping as many people as I can. 4.1 million and counting, in fact. I only wish I could do more.

Comment: @sfdcfox if an answer says it got 10K views, then those 10K views are overall (public +logged in) or 10k views from logged in users...

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It's all views (public + logged in), but also as an algorithm that the answer has to scroll in to view to count (e.g. simply looking at the question won't bump views for all answers).